# File in Amazon S3 bucket denied after making bucket public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have made my Amazon S3 bucket public, by going to its Permissions tab, and setting public access to everyone:

- List objects
- Write objects
- List bucket permissions
- Write bucket permissions

There is now an orange "Public" label on the bucket.

But when I go into the bucket, click on one of the images stored there, and click on the Link it provides, I get Access Denied. The link looks like this:

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/[bucket-name]/images/36d03456fcfaa06061f.jpg

Why is it still unavailable despite setting the bucket's permissions to public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to set [Object Level Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-object-permissions.html) on each object that you want to be available to the internet as Read Object.

or, you can use [Bucket Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to make this more widely permissioned, and not worry about resetting the permissions on each upload:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in that case, what's the point of making the bucket public as I did? It seems not to have made any difference.

Comment: That's an overarching setting, they are subtractive permissions, so the least permissive policy wins. A safety net if you like, to stop accidental data leakage.

Comment: Does that mean that if I use one of your solutions above, the bucket still needs to be `public`?

Comment: The Access Control List is for permissions via the S3 API, for things like a Lambda Function reading an object, rather than the Static Website style of delivery to anonymous internet users.